# Como es el flujo para cobrar suscripciones?

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy intentando implementar el siguiente flujo [Plans and Subscriptions](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/plans-and-subscriptions/)

Cuando llego al paso de suscribir un cliente a un plan el encabezado dice:
"Realiza un POST especificando el identificador del plan y del customer a asociar (el customer debe tener cargada una `default_card` a la cual se le cobrará, apta para pagos de suscripciones)"

A pesar de que he buscado bastante no encuentro a que se refiere con `default_card` , deduzco que debe ser una tarjeta simplemente asignada al cliente por lo que sigo la siguiente guía [Customer and Cards](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/charge-with-creditcard/javascript/)

Cuando llego al final puedo realizar el pago perfectamente pero esto no es lo que quiero ya que quiero suscribir a mi usuario a un plan, así que sigo investigando y encuentro esto [Charge with cards](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/customers-and-cards/)

Para poder crear una tarjeta asignada a un usuario dice:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/customers/[CUSTOMER_ID]/cards?access_token=TEST-7019883171081771-051423-224e9f156ecb76b25f428a9c7f69ae78-117317563' \
    -d '{"token": "ff8080814c11e237014c1ff593b57b4d"}'
```

Donde ese token que mando es el token que genere para la tarjeta:

- Se que el algoritmo para generarlo es correcto porque he podio ingresar pagos (aunque no suscripciones).

La respuesta es:

```
{
"message": "invalid parameters ",
"error": "bad_request",
"status": 400,
"cause": [
    []
]
```

}

Evidentemente esto es un bug o en la documentacion o en la misma aplicacion.

He intentado otras combinaciones por ejemplo mandando toda la informacion de la tarjeta que tengo disponible y no solo el token, esto no ha funcionado.

Alguien podria ayudarme a aislar el problema?

Comment: Pudiste resolver este tema? Tengo el mismo problema, me devuelve. { "message": "invalid parameters ", "error": "bad_request", "status": 400, "cause": [ [] ] } Estoy en modo sandbox.

Comment: no lametablemente, se ve que retiraron ese flujo por que no funcionaba